# exclude play route file -generated code from WartRemover

Tags: scala

I am using WartRemover in a play project. I want to exclude routes file (generated code from it) from Wartremover scanning. I added following but it still scans play `routes` generated code.

```
wartremoverExcluded ++= Seq("com.xxx.controllers.ReverseMyController","com.xxx.controllers.javascript.ReverseMyController","com.xxx.controllers.ref.ReverseMyController")
```

And it still shows wart errors from the generated code for `routes` play file. for e.g.

```
warn] /xxx/conf/routes:23: Inferred type containing Nothing
warn] PUT /service/myendpoint      com.xxx.controllers.MyController.postMyData
```

and same for many more routes defined in the routes file.

How to exclude routes from wartremover scan?

Comment: Not sure if this will help much but while I've noticed that `Wart.Nothing` seems to fail on the routes file even when it's been excluded, others such as `Wart.Any`, `Wart.Product` and `Wart.Serializable` seem to behave correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting `-Xprint:typer` in `scalacOptions` to see which package is the issue. It seems to work for me when I ignore the following

```
wartremoverExcluded ++= Seq("Routes", "controllers.ref")
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this question was asked in the context of wartremover 0.11, but if anyone finds themselves here looking for a solution for 0.12, this works for me:

```
wartremoverExcluded += sourceManaged.value / "main" / "routes_reverseRouting.scala"
wartremoverExcluded += sourceManaged.value / "main" / "routes_routing.scala"
```