# Wartremover still reports warts in excluded Play routes file

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt, scala-wartremover

I'm trying to add Wartremover to my Play project, but it keeps reporting warts on the routes file, even if I exclude it. I'm using Wartremover 0.14 and Play Framework 2.4.6.

The relevant part from my build.sbt:

```
wartremoverErrors ++= Warts.all
wartremoverExcluded += crossTarget.value / "routes" / "main" / "router" / "Routes.scala"
```

(Note that I have to do it differently than the answers in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26621728/exclude-play-route-file-generated-code-from-wartremover) suggest.)

Without the `wartremoverExcluded` line, Wartremover reports 13 errors in my routes file. With it, it still reports two: one about `Wart.Var` and one about `Wart.ExplicitImplicitTypes`. I can exclude these warts too, but using `Warts.allBut(Wart.Var, Wart.ExplicitImplicitTypes)`, but I'd prefer not to, because that excludes these warts from my entire codebase, not just the routes file.

Is there a way to make Wartremover stop reporting these warts on the route file, without excluding these warts for every file?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try adding these:

```
wartremoverExcluded += crossTarget.value / "routes" / "main" / "router" / "Routes.scala"
wartremoverExcluded += crossTarget.value / "routes" / "main" / "router" / "RoutesPrefix.scala"
wartremoverExcluded += crossTarget.value / "routes" / "main" / "controllers" / "ReverseRoutes.scala"
wartremoverExcluded += crossTarget.value / "routes" / "main" / "controllers" / "javascript" / "JavaScriptReverseRoutes.scala"
```

Edit: It's over a year since I first wrote this answer. `wartremoverExcluded` has been changed from a `SettingKey` to a `TaskKey`, so you can simplify the above to:

```
wartremoverExcluded ++= routes.in(Compile).value
```

For sbt 1.4+:

```
wartremoverExcluded ++= (Compile / routes).value
```

Or you could try this [sbt plugin I wrote to do it for you](https://github.com/danielnixon/sbt-ignore-play-generated).

Comment: Tested `wartremoverExcluded ++= (Compile / routes).value` with Play Framework 3.0, Scala 3.3.1, sbt 1.9.7 and wartremover 3.1.5 and it works. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
wartremoverExcluded ++= Seq(
  baseDirectory.value / "target" / "scala-2.11" / "src_managed" / "main" / "routes_routing.scala",
  baseDirectory.value / "target" / "scala-2.11" / "src_managed" / "main" / "routes_reverseRouting.scala"
)
```

(actually I'm on play 2.3, not sure if it's the same on 2.4.6)

Comment: I don't have the "src_managed" subdirectory. I guess Play 2.4.6 does it differently :).